# Use Yii2 RBAC for Restful API request

Tags: php, rest, api, yii2, rbac

I developed a web-app based on Yii2 Framework. The web-app use the RBAC system for action authorization depending on User Type (Admin, Employee, Sub-Employee). Now i'm developing a mobile-app and i created a new module "mobile" for controllers called by this mobile-app. In these new controller i set the behaviors function with CORS and authenticator and these work with no problem. I also set the RBAC system as i done for the web-app but in the mobile module don't work. Can someone help me setting authorization for controller/action?

```php
public function behaviors()
    {
        $behaviors = parent::behaviors();

        $behaviors['authenticator'] = [
            'class' => CompositeAuth::className(),
            'except' => ['index','view','test'],
            'authMethods' => [
                HttpBearerAuth::className(),
                HttpBasicAuth::className(),
                // QueryParamAuth::className(),
            ],
        ];

        $auth = $behaviors['authenticator'];
        unset($behaviors['authenticator']);

        $behaviors['corsFilter'] =
        [
            'class' => \yii\filters\Cors::className(),
            'cors' => [
                // restrict access to
                'Origin' => ['*'],
                // Allow only POST and PUT methods
                'Access-Control-Request-Method' => ['GET', 'POST', 'PUT', 'PATCH', 'DELETE', 'OPTIONS'],
                // // Allow only headers 'X-Wsse'
                'Access-Control-Request-Headers' => ['*'],
                // // Allow credentials (cookies, authorization headers, etc.) to be exposed to the browser
                'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' => false,
                // // Allow OPTIONS caching
                'Access-Control-Max-Age' => 3600,
                // // Allow the X-Pagination-Current-Page header to be exposed to the browser.
                'Access-Control-Expose-Headers' => ['X-Pagination-Current-Page'],
            ],

        ];



        $behaviors['authenticator'] = $auth;
        // avoid authentication on CORS-pre-flight requests (HTTP OPTIONS method)
        // $behaviors['authenticator']['except'] = ['OPTIONS', 'login'];
        $behaviors['access'] = 
        [
            'class' => AccessControl::className(),
            'rules' => [
                [
                    'allow' => true,
                    'actions' => ['create','view','update','delete','index', 'logout'],
                    'roles' => ['@'],
                    'denyCallback' => function ($rule, $action) {
                        throw new \yii\web\ForbiddenHttpException('You are not allowed to access this page');
                    }
                ],
                [
                    'allow' => true,
                    'actions' => ['login', 'index','test'],
                    'roles' => ['?'],
                    'denyCallback' => function ($rule, $action) {
                        throw new \yii\web\ForbiddenHttpException('You are not allowed to access this page');
                    }
                ],
            ],

        ];

        return $behaviors;
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Override the `checkAccess()` method of `ActiveController()`

`$behaviors['access']` is not the correct way to check access when you are using `yii\rest\ActiveController`, instead you are expected to override the `checkAccess()` method.

The documentation is [here](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/rest-controllers#performing-access-check) and [here](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-rest-activecontroller#checkAccess()-detail).

An example of how to do it:

```php
/**
 * Checks the privilege of the current user.
 *
 * This method should be overridden to check whether the current user has the privilege
 * to run the specified action against the specified data model.
 * If the user does not have access, a [[ForbiddenHttpException]] should be thrown.
 *
 * @param string $action the ID of the action to be executed
 * @param \yii\base\Model $model the model to be accessed. If `null`, it means no specific model is being accessed.
 * @param array $params additional parameters
 * @throws ForbiddenHttpException if the user does not have access
 */
public function checkAccess($action, $model = null, $params = [])
{
    // You could completely block some actions
    if ($action === 'delete') {

        throw new ForbiddenHttpException(
            Yii::t('app',
                'You are not allowed to {action} client models.',
                ['action' => $action]
            )
        );

    }

    // You could check if the current user has permission to run the action
    if ($action === 'index' && !Yii::$app->user->can('listClients')) {

        throw new ForbiddenHttpException(Yii::t('app',
            'You are not allowed to list clients'));

    }

    // You can also make the check more granular based on the model being accessed
    if ($action === 'view' && 
        !Yii::$app->user->can('viewClient', ['client_id' => $model->id])) {

        throw new ForbiddenHttpException(Yii::t('app',
            'You are not allowed to view client {client}',
            ['client' => $model->id]));            

    }
}
```

Looking at your example, it seems like you are only checking for authenticated users `@` or not-authenticated users, guests, `?`.

It is slightly confusing, since it is different on `yii\web\Controller`, but you should not be checking if the users are authenticated on `checkAccess()`, that check has already been performed by the `authenticator` filter, using the code that you posted with your question, by the time `checkAccess()` gets called, you will, always, have the application user, so `@` will **always** match, and `?` will **never** match.

Since you have commented out the following line:

```php
// $behaviors['authenticator']['except'] = ['OPTIONS', 'login'];
```

That means that CORS pre-flight requests will always fail, and also that guest users will never be able to login. Any requests that fail authentication will, immediately, result on a `401 unauthorized` response.

It seems like you are trying to let all authenticated users access all actions and unauthenticated users access only *login*, *index*, and *test* actions. If that is correct you don't need to use the `checkAccess()` method, and you can just uncomment the above line and add the actions there, as follows:

```php
$behaviors['authenticator']['except'] = ['options', 'login', 'index', 'test'];
```

Non authenticated users will be able to access only those actions.